# How to add multiple series in Excel dynamically

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following data in a excel

```
SERIES_NAME DATA_POINT1 DATA_POINT2 DATA_POINT3
S1 DP1V1 DP2V1 DPV1 DP4V1
S2 DP1V2 DP2V2 DP3V2 DP4V2
```

I want to make a template such that the chart is automatically redrawn everytime i add a new Series -

i.e S3,DP1V3,DP2V3,DP3V3,DP4V4

Any help or links is appreciated.

Edit: Adding requested details - Its a simple line chart. Im trying to create a template so that i can populate the data for N number of series in the excel through java and the chart is automatically populated with all series.

[image: Excel screenshot]

I want that as soon as user adds any new series in sheet, chart is automatically updated.

Comment: You've got 4 col headings with 5 values below them.  What kind of a chart and how are you plotting the data?

Comment: Better share some sample data in correct format (use Cooy & Paste) also, write what kind of Chart you are suppose to make, help us to fix the issue.☺

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

single click on your existing chart and click Ctrl-C to copy. Paste it to new location, (or you can Copy drag & drop by keeping Ctrl pressed while dragging)

Now you have an exact copy of your previous chart with previous data.

Menu - Design - Select Data (in Data area)

This will open a window in which you will have details of your previous chart.

In left pan (Legend entries, Click on Edit button,

in the new window that open,

in the top box click on the cell where S2 or S3 is put in your Excel Sheet (instead of S1), and

in the bottom box click on the range of cells where S3's data are there, Select all values together DP1V3,DP2V3,DP3V3,DP4V4.

close these settings window.

You chart now has S3's set of new data.

Comment: This doesnt solve my problemt. Updated question with more details.